# asp.net generic handler calling another handler

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to call another handler from within a handler? I have a custom handler that fires off whenever a file type is requested and then im going through some authentication process and need to call another handler.

My problem is i have no idea how to go about calling the other handler from within this handler.

Many Thanks

Comment: The short answer is: HttpWebRequest.Create.  Longer answer to follow

Answer (score 3):

An Http handler is just a class.  You can instantiate it just like any other class and calls its ProcessRequest method.

A better design, though, would be to avoid the handler-to-handler call, and instead move the common code into a utility class and call it from both handlers.

I'm assuming here you want the handler calls to share an HttpContext and request/response streams.  If you want the first handler to call the second handler, read its response,and return a response of its own, you're probably going to want to use Glenn's answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to call that `other handler`:

```
public class Handler1 : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

        var otherurl = "https://localhost:81/otherhandler.ashx";
        // using System.Net;
        var req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(otherurl);
        var sr = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
        // read stuff: sr.ReadBlock(), sr.ReadToEnd(), ...
        // do something with the response

        context.Response.Write("Hello World");

    }
}
```

Comment: Depending on the specifics of the handlers, you may need to add code to copy the original request into the "inner" request being send using the HttpWebRequest object, e.g. if the second handler is expecting any variables to be passed in a form/post or in the querystring, or if it has any dependencies on any of the standard http headers, e.g. user agent.